# How to draw a resizable polygon in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I have drawn the polygon by using the Core Graphics. But I can't able to resize the polygon. I used [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) to draw Polygon. This is my code

```
CGPoint gestureStartPoint,currentPosition;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        currentPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
        currentPath.lineWidth=1;
        xx1 = 30;
        yy1 = 30;
        xx = 30;
        yy = 30;  
        CGPoint gestureStartPoint,currentPosition;  
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if(drawColor==nil){
        [[UIColor redColor]setStroke];
        [currentPath stroke];
    }
    else {
        [drawColor setStroke];
        [currentPath stroke];
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        currentPosition.x = xx;
        currentPosition.y = yy;
        xx = gestureStartPoint.x;
        yy = gestureStartPoint.y;
        [currentPath moveToPoint:(currentPosition)];
        [currentPath addLineToPoint:(gestureStartPoint)];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This is the link of the sample [resizable Polygon](http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/flexible-polygon.html). How to draw the polygon with the resizable property like this? I don't know where to start to make a resizable polygon.

Comment: can i have ur email.. have to ask something.?

Comment: Hey! Thanx... will u add in Gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated than simply invoking some CoreGraphics magic.

To simply duplicate the logic on the site you linked to, I'd start by breaking down the problem:

Two types of gestures are recognized: taps, and tap-hold-drag.

Tap should add an x,y (point) to a list of points you are storing and redraw.

Tap-hold-drag should use the x,y location of the user's tap to determine the closest vertex - and you should probably do some max distance check as well. Once you've determined which vertex the user is "dragging", you can manipulate that point in your list and redraw.